# playFramework clear up mysql data when it inits?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework

Recently I am making a program using play1. It's all fine at the beginning.
But after I set `lower_case_table_names = 1` in MySQL, the data are cleared up every time the program starts.

Any advice?

Comment: Kindly add the code you have tried to make the question more clear and pin point to the place you are struck.The question is vague

Comment: As far as I know, play will create tables automatically in debug mode.When mysql in default setting, the value of lower_case_table_names is 0 and the The first letter of table name is  capitalized. It's all fine in this way. But after I set the value = 0, the letter of table name is in lowercase, but with the problem that has said above.

Comment: I have checked my application.conf, and it's same as the one in another project which works fine. so maybe the problem of database.

Comment: What do you mean by `play1`

Comment: Play has 2 version. Play1 supports java, and play2 supports scale.